# Cannot Update Component ('ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)')

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

During an authentication flow using `EXPO-ROUTER` I am getting the following Console Warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (`App`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `App`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
```

I'm new to React Native however, I believe this is telling me that it needs time to render the components before navigating. I have tried the link, but I think it's outdated.

In my `index.js`:

```
export default function App() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    console.log("HERE IS THE USER:", user);
    setUser(user);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = FIREBASE_AUTH.onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber;
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>LOADING...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    if (user) {
      router.replace("/(tabs)/Home");
    } else {
      router.replace("/(auth)/Onboard");
    }
  }
}
```